# First Review or opening date in Google places API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, google-places-api, foursquare

Im trying to obtain the date when a store was created on Google Places API, that information is not available on the API.I think, that I can do if I retrieve the first review date, but the API give me only 5 reviews.

Any ideas for obtain the date? or a similar service? I checked facebook and forsquare, but the same results.

Answer (score 0):

Currently this information is not exposed via Places API. There are following feature requests in Google issue tracker that you might be interested in:

- [Expose creation date and date of last update in Place Details](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35830022)
- [Google Places API Reviews, changing the sorting order?](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35821903)
- [Places API: Response to Include More Than 5 Reviews](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35825957)

I would suggest starring these feature requests to add your vote and subscribe to further notifications from Google. Hopefully one day they implement these feature requests.

Comment: Tranks, I will comment on the sorting order request